# Clicking button via python selenium chrome

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to click button "ja ik ga akkoord" on url anwb.nl with python selenium chrome. I have copied the relative xpath but when is use it i keep getting NoSuchElementException. Also id, name, etc no luck

I start with:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   options = Options()
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
   driver.get('https://anwb.nl')
```

When i inspect the page, xpath of the button gives me:

```
   //*[@id="accept default level"]
```

When i use this with ...by_xpath i get NoSuchElementException
The code of the button is:

```
   <button class="btn-decide_link-internal" type="button"
   name="save"
   id="accept default level"> ==$0
   Ja, ik ga akkoord</button>
```

I tried id (accept def...), name (save), but all nosuchelement

In general i would really like to understand how to interpret the web code in general can solve future problems.

Comment: I opened this page but I don't see this button

Comment: anwb.nl should get you to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with text as **Ja, ik ga akkoord** is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.anwb.nl/");
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='anwb']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-decide_link-internal"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.anwb.nl/");
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'anwb')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='accept default level']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
  - Browser snapshot:

[image: anwb]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Where this Nasdaq come from :(

Comment: For newbies to iframe check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhRx99uFUNk Helped me to understand better

Answer (score 1):

There is an `iframe`.Induce `WebDriverWait` and switch to frame first and then click on the button.

**EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()**

**EC.element_to_be_clickable()**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://anwb.nl')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME,"iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"accept default level"))).click()
```

Comment: Not always.However in your case there is an iframe which stopping you access the element until you switch it to.

Comment: So in general: if I get an unexpected Nosuchelement I can check if the element is in an 'iframe'. In this example it is <iframe src = https://272. . . > <br> I will dig in iframe. Wonder if there can be more iframe on one page

Comment: Yes that’s correct.Sometimes there can be nested iframe on a page.